# HTML/CSS - Text-decoration does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner of HTML and CSS.
So, now I'm in trouble. The `text-decoration: none;` does not work for me.
Can you guys help me to find a solution?

```css
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

#Header {
  width: auto;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #647551;
  margin-left: 0px;

}

#Header ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #645789;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="css/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Talkody - Gilles </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="Header">
         <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <p>Dit is een test website waar ik alles uittest, hierna ga ik er verder op in</p>
      <img source="images/Logo/TalkodyLogo.ai" />

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it has no decoration already.

Comment: `li`'s do not have text decoration by default. Check the rest of your CSS.

Comment: No? I'm running it in Chrome and I see the 'bullets' at the begining of each word.

Comment: use list-style none instead. like this #Header ul { list-style:none;}

Comment: Text decoration refers to the line underneath links.

Comment: I found it! Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply  `list-style-type: none;` to remove bullets

See below:

```css
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

#Header {
  width: auto;
  height: 70px;
  
  margin-left: 0px;

}

#Header ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #645789;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;

}
```

```html
<body>
      <div id="Header">
         <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <p>Dit is een test website waar ik alles uittest, hierna ga ik er verder op in</p>
      <img source="images/Logo/TalkodyLogo.ai" />

   </body>
```

```
text-decoration: none;
```

will remove below text decorations

```
underline     Defines a line below the text 
overline      Defines a line above the text 
line-through  Defines a line through the text
```

Answer (score 0):

The text has no decoration already, so if what you want it's to remove the bullets from the list, then use:

```
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove bullets from ul try:

```
#header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

When you want to delete underline from links use:

```
#header li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this to your CSS :

```
#header ul {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}

#Header {
  width: auto;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #647551;
  margin-left: 0px;

}

#Header ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #645789;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style:none;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link href="css/Main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Talkody - Gilles </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="Header">
         <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <p>Dit is een test website waar ik alles uittest, hierna ga ik er verder op in</p>
      <img source="images/Logo/TalkodyLogo.ai" />

   </body>
</html>
```